# How to let If-loop running all the time

Tags: python, if-statement

i would like to know how i let my program to check the if-statement all the time while the others functions still running.

```
def back():
   print("back")
counter = 0
while counter <= 1:
   if statement == True:
      print("hey")
      counter += 1
back()
```

Here the statement has to be True before the function back can be executed, but I want it all at the same time to run

Comment: You might be looking for threads or asynchronous I/O. When the statement is True what do you need to do? https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/  https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? This will trigger `back()` to run in the background every time statement is `True` and it will store a reference to the background process in `background_processes`

```
import multiprocessing

def back():
   print("back")

counter = 0
background_processes = []
while counter <= 1:
   if statement == True:
      print("hey")
      p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=back)
      p1.start()                                  # back() will run in the background and this loop will keep going       
      background_processes.append(p1)
      counter += 1
```